# Problem 101 The Blocks Problem UVA gives runtime-error on submission. works fine on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, runtime-error, cuda-uva

I have been trying to solve the UVA 101 The Blocks Problem. I wrote the solution in C++ and ran the sample input. It gives the correct output on visual studio code but on submitting on UVA it gives runtime error. Any advice to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Here's my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;


void returnAllPos(int x, vector<vector<int>> &blocks){
    while(blocks[x].back() != x){
         int idx = blocks[x].back();
         blocks[x].pop_back();
         if(blocks[idx].size() == 0){
            blocks[idx].push_back(idx);
         }
         else{
            returnAllPos(idx, blocks);
         }
    }
}

void outputBlocks(vector<vector<int>> &blocks){
    for(int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++){
        cout << i << ":";
        for(int j = 0; j < blocks[i].size(); j++){
            cout << " " << blocks[i][j];
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

void onto(int a, int b, vector<vector<int>> &blocks){
    returnAllPos(a, blocks);
    returnAllPos(b, blocks);
    blocks[b].push_back(a);
    blocks[a].pop_back();
}

void over(int a, int b, vector<vector<int>> &blocks){
    returnAllPos(a, blocks);
    // find B and put a on top
    for(int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++){
        if(find(blocks[i].begin(), blocks[i].end(), b) != blocks[i].end()){
            blocks[i].push_back(blocks[a].back());
            blocks[a].pop_back();
        }
        
    }
}

bool samestack(int a, int b, vector<vector<int>> &blocks){
    for(int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++){
        if(find(blocks[i].begin(), blocks[i].end(), b) != blocks[i].end() && find(blocks[i].begin(), blocks[i].end(), a) != blocks[i].end()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void pileover(int a, int b, vector<vector<int>> &blocks){
    for(int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < blocks[i].size(); j++){
            if(blocks[i][j] == a){
                int end = blocks[i].back();
                std::reverse((blocks[i].begin() + j), blocks[i].end());
                while(1){
                    int elem = blocks[i].back();
                    blocks[i].pop_back();
                    blocks[b].push_back(elem);
                    if(elem == end) return;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

void pileonto(int a, int b, vector<vector<int>> &blocks){
    returnAllPos(b, blocks);
    pileover(a, b, blocks);    
}

int main(void){
    int size = 0;

    cin >> size; // read the first line
    if(size < 1 || size > 25) return 1;
    vector<vector<int>> blocks(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        blocks[i].push_back(i);
    }

    //outputBlocks(blocks);

    std::string first, second;
    
    int a, b;
    while(1){
        cin >> first;
        if(first == "quit") break;
        cin >> a >> second >> b;
        if(samestack(a, b, blocks) || a == b) 
            continue;
        if((a >= 0 && b >= 0) && (a < size && b < size)){
            if(first == "pile"){
                if(second == "onto"){
                    pileonto(a, b, blocks);
                }
                else if(second == "over"){
                    pileover(a, b, blocks);
                }
            }
            else if(first == "move"){
                if(second == "over")
                    over(a, b, blocks);
                else if(second == "onto")
                    onto(a, b, blocks);
            }
        }
        //cin.ignore();   
    }
    
    outputBlocks(blocks);


    return 0;
}
```

I followed every instruction given in the problem description. My code gives run-time error on UVA.

Comment: What is the actual problem you have on which line does it fail? And have you debugged the problem yet? If so what did you see on the line that failed?

Comment: Please show a [mre] including inputs, expected outputs, error messages and a description of what the code is supposed to do

Comment: What will `returnAllPos` do when the vector is empty? Be sure to enable all warnings and pay attention to them. If you have access to AddressSanitizer or Valgrind they can also help with tracking down issues like this.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The run-time error occurs when I submit my code on UVA, locally There is not error. I am debugging the problem using multiple test cases.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for pointing this out. That behavior is undefined for now. I will look into it and this might be the root cause.

Comment: What site is that UVA?

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `blocks[i]` with `blocks.at(i)`. Is suspect you miss a case in which `blocks.back()` isn't valid

Comment: @PepijnKramer [link](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=37)
It's an online Judge

Comment: Looks like that is more oriented toward finding correct algorithms then it is a site to learn C++ from.

Comment: Good sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
 For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I can't thank you enough! I had always wanted to ask this from an experienced developer and yet had no way! Thank YOU! Where can I talk to you? If possible. such as email etc. I picked C++ and I want to master it.

Comment: Just work through those materials I send you and if you have any concrete questions (on code you've written) then just ask them here again. Try to work your way to understanding the C++ core guidelines. These guidelines limits itself to a subset of C++ (so you don't have to learn all off it, and certainly not the "C" style coding examples that still persist.)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I will work on the material. By "here" do you refer to stack overflow or this thread? Thank you once again!

Comment: C++ Stack overflow ;)